# Prevent react-router re-creating component when switching links

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a number of nav links at the top level that switch page level components in and out when you switch between the links. Some pages have complex grid components that are expensive to create. I noticed that react-router constructs the component every time a page is switched. Is there a way to cache the component passed into a route?, i.e PositionsPage

`<Route path="/positions" component={PositionsPage} />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very important performance consideration in React as a whole (and not just `react-router`).

By default design, React re-renders the complete DOM tree for any change in `props` or `state`.

Here is a summary of techniques that the [React documentation for Advanced Performance](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/advanced-performance.html) suggests.

### Use the production build

**NOTE**: Correctness of components is automatically taken care of. Nothing to worry.

This should be fairly simply. The following `webpack.config.js` plugins section snippet should make sure that the `NODE_ENV` variable reaches the React source code.

```
  ...
  plugins: [
    new CommonsChunkPlugin('bundle.js'),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
      }
    })
  ]
  ...
```

Now just ensure the `NODE_ENV=production webpack -p`.

This ensures that all those warnings/errors and `propTypes` checking is skipped.

### Avoiding reconciling the DOM

**WARNING**: You must handle all possible condition matrices (if needed) of `props` and `state` to make sure you don't mess up the correctness of rendering.

This is the callback signature which must be implemented. This is called whenever any `state` or `prop` value changes.

```
shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
  // @TODO your logic here
  // return true to update, false otherwise
  return true;
}
```

> Keep in mind that React will invoke this function pretty often, so the
>   implementation has to be fast.

Comment: I'm aware of these advanced performance techniques, which I've implemented in my code. 

My thoughts are that react-router should support a mode where links may be represented as tabs which in a tabbed pane. In some cases, it's more desirable to show/hide the components rather than reconstructing them every time. Perhaps there is a way to use the programmable API to add history so I can get to one of these tabs via a url, but perform the showing / hiding myself.

Comment: The API is available. `browserHistory.push` is what you use to add to the Browser's `History API`.

Comment: And I don't think React Router can & should add such a feature. Because react router does not know what components are you putting in and how do they behave. So each component must implement its own update behavior anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine the expensive components together into one and just hide the portions you don't need with css styles.