# React Router calls component constructor when switching routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using react and react-router for a SPA which has a navigation. The router is calling the react component 'constructor' every time a navigation item is switched. Here is the relevant bit of code:

```
class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log('component constructed!');
        this.state = {
            counter: 0
        }
        setInterval(() => this.setState({
            counter: this.state.counter+1
        }), 1000)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <h3>Counter: {this.state.counter}</h3>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={Home} />
            <Route path="profile" component={Profile} />
            <Route path="settings" component={Settings} />
        </Route>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Every time I switch from one tab to another, the counter starts from 0. 
Obviously I understand that `render()` should be called every time its state changes or when router switches tabs, but why call `constructor` for change of tab?! Is that how react-router works, or am I doing something wrong?

This question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38460633/prevent-react-router-re-creating-component-when-switching-links), but the accepted answer talks about 're-rendering' and not re-construction of the component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The constructor is called every time that a component mounts. Each time that you navigate to the location `/`, the `<Home>` component will mount. When you navigate to another location, the `<Home>` component will unmount. If you want the state to be persistent across navigation, it should be kept higher up the tree.